# Salesforce Apex Scheduled Class - Call action from another extention

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

need help please! question regarding Salesforce Apex Scheduled class.

I need to call an action from visual force page the action located on the apex class. The apex class is quite long to post, but the action totally works from VF page.

Here is sample version of the code. But scheduled class doesn't work, just keep giving errors to save.

VF Page

<apex:page standardController="Account" Extensions="ProvisionAccount">
<apex:commandButton value="Proceed" action="{!provision}" rendered="{!renderProceedButton}" onComplete="window.close();" />

Here is my code that I can't make it work:

```
global class AutoProv implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List <Account> A = [SELECT Id FROM Account
            WHERE ToBeProcessed__C = True  ];   
     ProvisionAccount.provision(A);
      
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to call action from VF or Apex Class

Answer (score 0):

You have not created new instance to your controller class and simply passing the list of accounts as a parameter .
Can you please try the below code and test whether it is working or not

```
global class AutoProv implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List <Account> A = [SELECT Id FROM Account
            WHERE ToBeProcessed__C = True  ];   
    ProvisionAccount sch = new ProvisionAccount(A);
      
    }
}
```